# vimscript: how to reload buffer content without changing focus

Tags: vim

I have the following function in my .vimrc:

```
function s:get_errors()
  let term_buf = filter(map(getbufinfo(), 'v:val.bufnr'), 'getbufvar(v:val, "&buftype") is# "terminal"')[0]
  let lines = getbufline(term_buf, 1, '$')
  let text = join(lines, "\n")
  echo text
endfunction

command PrintErrors call s:get_errors()
```

My vim session has two buffers: one with my code being edited, and one with a terminal emulator (`:term`) where building happens (a process is monitoring the FS for file changes and trigger a build each time a file is modified).

My ultimate goal is to process the content of the terminal buffer to extract file path. My current command simply `echo`s the content of the terminal buffer.
When I save a code modification, the build happens and might report errors. I see them right away in the terminal buffer, but `getbufline` seems to have some "lag" and still returns the old content. After some time, the content is updated.
If I manually switch to the terminal buffer and back, the content is updated.

My goal is to make sure `getbufline` always returns the latest available content, and I can't seem to do that using vimscript. How can I refresh to content of the terminal buffer without manually changing the focus to it and back ?

Comment: See `:help TextChangedT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of starting the terminal with `:term`, you could try a custom command that uses `term_start` ([`:help term_start()`](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#term_start%28%29)). That function allows you to install a callback that is run on every line of output of the terminal. Something like this:

```
function! HandleOutput(job, line)
  echomsg "Got line: " .. a:line
endfunction

let job = term_start('irb', { 'out_cb': function('HandleOutput') })
```

There's a practical problem for irb -- the output contains ANSI escape codes for color and text formatting. You don't get the *buffer* contents, you get the raw output. But you could strip out these codes, or look for a way to start your build process with no color.

Comment: FWIW, `irb` [apparently](https://github.com/ruby/irb/releases/tag/v1.3.6) supports [$NO_COLORS](https://no-color.org/).

Comment: Indeed, thanks ! I'll see how to deals with colors and control code, but I'm getting the output as soon as it is created \o/